# constructor vs componentWillMount; what a componentWillMount can do that a constructor cannot?

Tags: javascript, class, reactjs, constructor, ecmascript-6

As far as I could see, the only thing a `componentWillMount` can do and a `constructor` cannot is to call `setState`.

```
componentWillMount() {
    setState({ isLoaded: false });
}
```

Since we have not called `render` yet, a `setState` in `componentWillMount` will prepare the state object before we enter the first `render()` pass. Which is essentially the same thing a `constructor` does:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoaded: false };
}
```

---

But I see another use case where `componentWillMount` is useful (on server side).

Let's consider something asynchronous:

```
componentWillMount() {
    myAsyncMethod(params, (result) => {
        this.setState({ data: result });
    })
}
```

Here we cannot use the `constructor` as assignment to `this.state` won't trigger `render()`.

What about `setState` in `componentWillMount`? According to [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount):

> `componentWillMount()` is invoked immediately before mounting occurs. It
>   is called before `render(`), therefore setting state in this method will
>   not trigger a re-rendering. Avoid introducing any side-effects or
>   subscriptions in this method.

So, here I think React will use the new state value for the first render and avoids a re-render.

**Question 1:** Does this means, inside `componentWillMount`, if we call `setState` in an async method's callback (can be a promise callback), React **blocks initial rendering** until the callback is executed?

Having this setup on **client-side** (yes I see that use case in server-side rendering), if I assume the above is true, I will not see anything until my asynchronous method completes.

Am I missing any concepts?

**Question 2:** Are the any other use cases that I can achieve with `componentWillMount` only, but not using the `constructor` and `componentDidMount`?

Comment: *Question 1: Does this means, inside componentWillMount, if we call setState in an async method's callback (can be a promise callback), React blocks initial rendering until the callback is executed?"* Surely not -- how would it know? React is powerful, but not magical.

Comment: I want to know whether my first question is completely valid, otherwise I would like to know what are the real use cases for `componentWIllMount`. Sorry for asking two questions in a question. I didn't want to duplicate all my research stories in another question. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Does this means, inside componentWillMount, if we call setState in an
>   async method's callback (can be a promise callback), React blocks
>   initial rendering until the callback is executed?

**No, see** [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lustoykov/wk2eufdz/).

The following code doesn't block render (bear in mind this would be an anti pattern anyways to call setState there)

```
componentWillMount: function() {
     new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(()=> {
            resolve();
        }, 2000)
     }).then(() => this.setState({ promiseResult: 'World' }));
  },
```

> Question 2: Are the any other use cases that I can achieve with
>   componentWillMount only, but not using the constructor and
>   componentDidMount?

**No, for ES6 classes you can discard componentWillMount**. It is only needed if you use `React.createClass({... })`

EDIT: Apparently, I'm wrong. Thanks to @[Swapnil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3920820/swapnil) for pointing this out. Here is the [discussion](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/129).

React throws a warning if there is a side effect in the `constructor` which modifies state in another component, because it assumes that `setState` in the `constructor` itself and potentially during `render()` is being called. So no side effects in the `constructor` are desired.

This is not the case if you do it in `componentWillMount`, no errors are thrown. On the other hand, the guys from facebook discourage side effects in `componentWillMount` also. So if you don't have any side effects, you could use the `constructor` instead of `componentWillMount`. For side effects it is recommended to use `componentDidMount` instead of `componentWillMount`.
Either way, you don't need `componentWillMount`.

Comment: For ES6 if I am using Redux and want to dispatch an action on initial load, it is suggested to dispatch the action in componentWillMount instead of the constructor. [It says that over here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/129)

Comment: One more thing. My name is Swapnil not Swapnii :p

Comment: I need glasses;-)

Comment: @leo, In the fiddle you shared I put a log inside `render()`. What I observed was, React renders a "Hello" on first render. Then after 2s, the timeout happens, `setState` is called from `componentWillMount`. React updated the new state value on the DOM, though it **did not** re-render!! That's mysterious for me! How did it update DOM without re-rendering? (I am pretty sure, I am missing something here about React).

Comment: I am sorry, it was my eyes betrayed me!! You're right, yes it re-renders. Oh now I get it, the `setState` is not called from `componentWillMount` closure. It is called from another scope, the env of the call back function; thus triggered the render. So the react docs are right, `setState` inside `componentWillMount` does not trigger a re-render :)