# React Uncaught TypeError: search.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to play around with the wikipedia API. I'm using Axios to make a request for the data. When I go to map through the prop passed through from App's state, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: search.map is not a function
```

I have checked that the intended value is an array. It seems to be, I can manipulate it as such in the react dev tools console. It also has a proto of Array, so I'm confused as to why I can't do this.

Root Component:

```
class App extends React.Component
{
  constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.state = {search: {}}
    this.wikiSearch();
  }
  wikiSearch()
  {
    axios
      .get('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search="test"')
      .then ((result) => {
        result.data.shift();
        this.setState({search: result.data});
      });
    }
  render ()
  {
    return(
    <div id="container">
      <Header />
      <SearchBar />
      <SearchList search={this.state.search} />
    </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

The component that uses state data from App

```
class SearchList extends React.Component
{
  render()
  {
    let search = this.props.search;
    search.map((element) => {

    });
    return(
      <div id='SearchList'>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Because the prop you transferred "search" which you set on App state is "Object", not an Array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize `search` as an empty array variable, not object, in your component state so that it's not throw erro on calling `map` method on it like this:

```
this.state = {search: []}
```

not like this:

```
this.state = {search: {}}
```

Comment: why do you suggest initializing state inside `componentWillMount`?  could you please justify? we had a discussion about that here http://stackoverflow.com/q/40828004/5069226