# Constructor vs componentWillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In ReactJs, what can we do using componentWillMount that we cannot do via the constructor? Both are called once and before the component is rendered.

```js
import React from 'react';

class Display extends React.Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props)   
    console.log('Display.Constructor...')
    console.log(this.props)
  
  }


  componentWillMount(){
    console.log('Display.componentWillMount...')
    console.log(this.props)
  }
```

Comment: You are not using componentWillUpdate in your code.

Comment: @kojow7 Thanks. Fixed the typo.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount "Generally, we recommend using the `constructor()` instead."

Comment: You should look into the React Lifecycle methods: https://engineering.musefind.com/react-lifecycle-methods-how-and-when-to-use-them-2111a1b692b1 and https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-reactjs-component-life-cycle-823a640b3e8d both may be useful pages for you to read.

Comment: @fahmi, have you checked the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828004/constructor-vs-componentwillmount-what-a-componentwillmount-can-do-that-a-const

Answer (score 2):

I believe that from React 17, `ComponentWillMount` will have to be prefixed with UNSAFE_ in order to be used and its use is discouraged.

I think the only thing you can't achieve inside the constructor that you can with `ComponentWillMount` is to `setState()` also react throws a warning if anything inside your constructor modifies state even in another component.

There is a thread [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/129) that may be of interest to you on this topic.

Comment: setState do not work inside componentWillMount