# How should I alternate componentWillMount()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React.js, and as you know, componentWillMount() is going to be deprecated.
I wanna replace my `componentWillMount`s.

I'm going to move its logics into `constructor`. Is there any difference between executing some logic in `componentWillMount` and in `constructor`?

For example,

before

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      doSomething();
    }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.name} </div>
  }
}
```

after

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      doSomething();
    }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.name} </div>
  }
}
```

Also, when doSomething is setState, is there any difference setting state in constructor and in public prop?

in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = { foo: 1 };
}
```

in public prop

```
state = { foo: 1 };
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [constructor vs componentWillMount; what a componentWillMount can do that a constructor cannot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828004/constructor-vs-componentwillmount-what-a-componentwillmount-can-do-that-a-const)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`constructor` is not the right place for performing some actions. Because it will hold other operations until it's finished.

`componentDidMount` is the right choice because it's an asynchronous function so that actions are run in the background and there'll be no hamper in the UI rendering.

---

Here's a [list](https://medium.com/@marikalam/react-basic-constructor-componentdidmount-and-render-9476f8d28f0f) that you can choose when to use between `constructor` and `componentDidMount`:

## constructor

**Do:**

- initialize state
- bind event handlers

If you don't initialize a state and you don't bind methods, you don't need to implement the constructor.

**Don't:**

Avoid introducing any side-effects or subscriptions. Do not set state by using setState() in the constructor.

## componentDidMount

**Do:**

- initialization that requires DOM nodes
- load data from a remote endpoint (where to instantiate the network request)
- set up any subscriptions (don’t forget to unsubscribe in componentWillUnmount())

---

You may also be interested to [read the comment](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/302) from the creator of react, Dan Abramov:

> *I won't like to wait for the component to be mounted to dispatch an ajax call to fulfill the component data dependencies. I would like to do it as soon as possible, like in the constructor, not even in componentWillMount.*
>
> If it's an async request, it won't be fulfilled by the time the component mounts anyway, regardless of where you fire it. This is because JS is single threaded, and the network request can't "come back" and be handled while we are still rendering. So the difference between firing it earlier and later is often negligible.
>
> You're right that it matters in some rare cases though and for those cases it might make sense to break the recommendation. But you should be extra cautious as state can update before mounting, and if your data depends on state, you might have to refetch in that case. In other words: when in doubt, do it in componentDidMount.
>
> The specific recommendation to avoid side effects in the constructor and Will* lifecycles is related to the changes we are making to allow rendering to be asynchronous and interruptible (in part to support use cases like this better). We are still figuring out the exact semantics of how it should work, so at the moment our recommendations are more conservative. As we use async rendering more in production we will provide a more specific guidance as to where to fire the requests without sacrificing either efficiency or correctness. But for now providing a clear migration path to async rendering (and thus being more conservative in our recommendations) is more important.

---

For further interest, you may also [visit this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980977/why-is-componentwillreceiveprops-deprecated/51981144).

Comment: FYI, Dan Ambrov is not the creator of React. He created Redux.

Answer (score 3):

getDerivedStateFromProps is invoked right before calling the render method, both on the initial mount and on subsequent updates. It should return an object to update the state, or null to update nothing.
So If you want to perform some action just once, on before mount of component, then getDerivedStateFromProps is not appropriate option.

Use componentDidMount method.
Have more details in https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html

Answer (score 1):

Use `getDerivedStateFromProps()` it's next method called after constructor.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: Just moving into `constructor` is not enough?

Comment: This is not right choice. How would you perform some actions without receiving the props?

Answer (score 1):

setState in a constructor will perform unnecessary computation, you can either use the state property as you suggest or `this.state = { ... }` in your constructor if you need to perform more computation or access props.

The [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount) recommends you use constructor (or a class property) over componentWillMount for initialising state. For side-effects (e.g. http request) that could update state you should consider componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate. With asynchronous state updates, you should always make sure that your component handles the state without that data.

Comment: Sorry, the code in the question was wrong! I wanna compare `this.state=` in constructor and `state=` as public props of the component.

Comment: No problem. These two approaches are very similar but `this.state =` in the constructor allows you to access props however initialising state from props can be dangerous https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e.