# ReactJS same components

Tags: reactjs, api

In ReactJS if I have components that get data from an API(it was called inside ComponentDidMount lifecycle) and I use the component multiple times, does it call 5 times as well?
Note: Same API, Same URL all is same I just used it multiple times.

Because if it called 5 times does it will be more efficient if I call the API outside the components and just feed the data so it will only be called once?

Comment: Is it more efficient if I just call the API at the constructor at the top level(app level) and feed the feed to the components? Hmmm

Comment: This will help you to decide whether to call api in constructor or componentdidmount https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092341/how-should-i-alternate-componentwillmount/52092495#52092495

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's calling the data in every single component's *componentDidMount()* event and for this reason, If the data, URL, and everything will be same, you need to call it in parent component and pass data to child components using **props** or **redux**.