# How to this setState to set a value from function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having problem with settings state value with a value returned from a function. Somehow, the state only bind itself to the function itself.
How can I fix this?

Here is my constructor:

```
    this.state = {
        text: getText
    }
```

Here is the function that retrieves the

```
getText= () => {
    $.get('/webapi/gettext, function (data) {
        return data;
    }.bind(this));
};
```

but this works if I have it in the constructor.

```
constructor{
        $.get('/webapi/gettext, function (data) {
                        this.setState({ text: data });
        }.bind(this));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use `componentDidMount` hook:

```
componentDidMount() {
  $.get('/webapi/gettext, (data) => {
    this.setState({ text: data });
  });
}
```

For further help, see my [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092341/how-should-i-alternate-componentwillmount/52092495#52092495).

Comment: Or should I just have it in the constructor? What would be the right way? I thought by having it in a function and call it from the constructor would be better?

Comment: $.get('/webapi/GetStartupThings, (data) => {
    this.setState({ text: data });
  });¨

I actually got 2 jquery which retrieves data.

Comment: Is it possible to call function form the component Did mount instead? As I'm going to use this jquery function more places.

Comment: If you're going to use the same in more places, then create a new function and inside that place the logic `$.get()` code and use them in `componentDidMount(){callYourfunction()}` and where ever you want.

Comment: I see now that there are cases where I'm sending a parameter event and cases not. is it possible to use the same function or do I have to use two functions with same code?