# In react native what should i use instead of componentWillMount

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asyncstorage

ComponentWillMount has been renamed and deprecated, and is not recommended to be used

```
  constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  cartItems: []
};}


componentWillMount() {
AsyncStorage.getItem("CART", (err, res) => {
  if (!res) this.setState({ cartItems: [] });
  else this.setState({ cartItems: JSON.parse(res) });
});}
```

what should I do  to fetch the cartItems before rendering ??

Comment: This answer can be useful [how-should-i-alternate-componentwillmount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092341/how-should-i-alternate-componentwillmount)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a rule of thumb. Does your old code (which implements `componentWillMount`) performs any side effect? Case no it's just an initialization and you can do it inside `constructor`. Case you need to perform a side effect (API call for example) you should use `componentDidMount` instead

```
state = { cartItems : [] } 

componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("CART", (err, res) => {
        if (!res) this.setState({ cartItems: [] });
        else this.setState({ cartItems: JSON.parse(res) });
    });
}
```

Comment: and for cases when the component is already mounted, sometimes navigation.navigate doesnt make a fresh new api call , so its better you do navigation.push to make the component realogn itself at top of stack and make fresh new api calls or whatever you want to do inside it.

Comment: Notice, `componentDidMount` it's a great place to fetch **initial** data. If your data must change uppon a `prop / state` update, then you should take a look at `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: correct , but sometimes componentDidUPdate is risky , coz it goes in a loop if not handled properly

Comment: Just in case you have issue with Asyncstorage, place your code in "async" function and use await before Asyncstorage.getItem(), and call this function in ComponentDidMount

Comment: so if i use flatlist and i want to rerender flatlist to get  the new data from api i should use componentDidMount?

can you give me an example

Comment: `componentDidMount` to fetch initial data and `componentDidUpdate` to update your data based on a `prop/state` change

Comment: You can use `NavigationEvents` for this purpose if you are using `react-navigation` it will work flawlessly. I was having the same problem of `ComponentDidMount` not being called when I switched between screens so the best way is to use `NavigationEvents`. Use the onWillFocus method. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html