# componentWillMount is deprecated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As the official docs say `componentWillMount` is deprecated now and is recommended to put
any code that is meant for this lifecycle method into the constructor.

Honestly I don't know how to do that. I've got this code that was meant for `componentWillMount`
but how I'm supposed to implement it into the constructor:

```js
if (window.localStorage.getItem("authToken"))
  this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
```

I had it like this:

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    users: [],
    username: "",
    email: "",
    title: "something",
    isAuthenticated: false
  };
  if (window.localStorage.getItem("authToken"))
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
}
```

but the condition wasn't triggered when it was supposed to trigger. How are conditional statements supposed to work in a constructor ?

Any guidance much appreciated.

**Edit:**

```js
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {
    users: [],
    username: "",
    email: "",
    title: "something",
    isAuthenticated: window.localStorage.getItem("authToken") ? true : false
  };
}
```

I'll try this as this does make sense to me.

Comment: Have you considered putting it into componentDidMount()?

Comment: I've thought about it but if that would be a good idea it would've been mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I think setting the state in your constructor is not a good idea, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961853/what-will-happen-if-i-use-setstate-function-in-constructor-of-a-class-in-react

Comment: Thing to note don't store your auth token in localstorage you are exposing it to XSS attacks

Comment: please check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092341/how-should-i-alternate-componentwillmount?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect the exact flow of componentWillMount, and requires you to think in a slightly different way.

You can do this.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  if (window.localStorage.getItem("authToken"))
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
}


render() {
  // Since this function will be called before
  // componentDidMount, handle the false case here

  if (!this.state.isAuthenticated) {
    return null; // or any fallback UI for unAuthenticated user 
  }

  return (
   // the original UI
  )
}
```