# Call React component's function before its render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to load article from DB and set it like a component's state. Then this article should be shown on the page. But when I try to do this, there is an error that the value of loaded article's state is undefined. So, I think that the problem occures because the loading data function is called after the component's render. How can I call this function before rendering and properly show state's value?

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';  
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class ArticlePage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      article: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { onLoad } = this.props;

    // gets full list of articles
    axios('http://localhost:8080/api/articles')
      .then((res) => onLoad(res.data))
  }

  getArticle() {
    // gets current article
    // ...
  }

  render() {

    this.getArticle();
    const { article } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
      <h1>
        {article.title}
      </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  articles: state.home.articles,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  onLoad: data => dispatch({ type: 'HOME_PAGE_LOADED', data }),
  onDelete: id => dispatch({ type: 'DELETE_ARTICLE', id }),
  setEdit: article => dispatch({ type: 'SET_EDIT', article }),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(ArticlePage));
```

Comment: In render get console.log(this.props non state) and check if data is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting state for `article` so it seems that you are obtaining the value of `article` in getArticles. You are also calling `getArticles` in render which will cause the re-render which will lead you to infinite loop.

In addition to making checks such as `{ article && article.title }`,

So, in componentDidMount, call the `getArticles` function after you do the fetch.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    const { onLoad } = this.props;

    // gets full list of articles
    axios('http://localhost:8080/api/articles')
      .then((res) => {
       onLoad(res.data);
       // call getArticles here.
       getArticles() {
        // code ...
       }
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You Should use [*componentWillMount*](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

```
async componentWillMount() {
    const {onLoad} = this.props;

    // gets full list of articles
    try {
        const res = await axios('http://localhost:8080/api/articles');
        onLoad(res.data);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, "error");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're [doing nothing wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092495/2138752). You just need to perform a check before you render the component so that you can avoid initial null value:

```
{ article && article.title }
```

Alternatively, you can also define empty value:

```
this.state = {
  article: {
    title: ''
  }
}
```

Ah, also pointed out by @gdh, you're making function call inside the render hook. Instead you should call that function inside the `componentDidMount` hook.