# ReactJs: How to execute code before a component mounts since componentWillMount is deprecated?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-lifecycle

I am trying to redirect user to home page conditionally before component mounts:

```
 componentWillMount(){
    console.log("componentWillMount is called.")
    let userHasNotChosenOpportunity = true
    if (userHasNotChosenOpportunity) {
      this.props.history.push("/home")
    }
  }
```

I have two problems:

1. `componentWillMount` never gets called
2. `componentWillMount` is deprecated and there seems to be no alternative to execute code before component mounts.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try calling the redirect inside constructor(props) {}

Comment: is it a problem for you to use componentDidMount?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I alternate componentWillMount()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092341/how-should-i-alternate-componentwillmount)

Comment: @SinanYaman the problem with that is render gets executed

Comment: @MarcCharpentier with componentDidMount render gets executed

Comment: I think this is tribble idea if u redirect user  into component using this functions , u should probably use route redirect or something like this for doing this!

Comment: @Jax-p the problem with componentDidMount and constructor is that render gets executed before redirecting

Comment: @b3hr4d how do I perform the condition check before component gets rendered

Comment: @AhmedGhrib There are more answers... The constructor is certainly called before rendering. Also getDerivedStateFromProps() is next method called after constructor - right before render(). See the whole [React life cycle](https://i2.wp.com/programmingwithmosh.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/Screen-Shot-2018-10-31-at-1.44.28-PM.png?ssl=1).

Comment: should make protected root for checking props like this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65178365/12608714

Comment: @Jax-p True, but the code inside render still gets executed. I need to redirect and to prevent the code inside render to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should try calling it on `componentDidMount` or if you for some reason really need to use `componentWillMount` you can use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount` but as indicated it is unsafe

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
const OpportunityRedirectRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  opportunities,
  ...rest
}) => {
  let userHasNotChosenOpportunity =
    Object.keys(opportunities.chosen_opportunity).length === 0 &&
    opportunities.chosen_opportunity.constructor === Object;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        userHasNotChosenOpportunity ? (
          <Redirect to="/courses" />
        ) : (
          <Component {...props} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

OpportunityRedirectRoute.propTypes = {
  opportunities: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  opportunities: state.opportunities,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(OpportunityRedirectRoute);
```

In App.js:

```
 <OpportunityRedirectRoute
              exact
              path="/opportunity"
              component={OpportunityPage}
            />
```